# Storing a String as a file in database in java

Tags: java

I want to turn the content of a String variable into (I don't know the the correct term) a file and store it in my database. I do not need the file physically and only need it stored in the database so I can download it later in the Frontend.

I want the operation to happen automatically in the Backend (Rest API turns a String variable into a file with the extension .pem and stores it in the database). Is it possible ? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: a String and a File are not the same. A file can have a String as content, depending on it's type. Sure, seems possible. What do you need help with, actually?

Comment: I am working with the AWS SDK for Java and trying to create Key Pairs. I can retrieve the private key as a String while creating the key pair and I need to store this String in the database as a file with the .pem extension and not as a varchar.

Comment: ok. so store it as a blob, and at download, transform it into a .pem again

Comment: Do I get to choose the name and the extension of the blob to download later on ? Could you show me an example please ?

Comment: a blob doesn't have a name or an extension. You'll have to define that during the download

Answer (score 0):

maybe what I think is you want to store some data in a File.If wrong, please inform me.
You need to import some packages for that :-

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.Scanner;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.util.Arrays;
```

Use the following code :-

```
public void writetoFile(String pathtofile, String text)
{
try{

File file = new File(pathtofile);
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file);
fw.write(text);
fw.close();
}
catch(IOException e){
System.out.println(e);
}
}

//If you want to read content from the file, you can get all lines in an array or other method you wish.

public String [] readfromFile(String path){
try{
File file = new File(path);
Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
String [] out = new String[1];
int i=0;
while(scan.hasNextLine()){
out[i]=scan.nextLine();
i++;
out = Arrays.copyOf(out,out.legnth+1);
}
}catch(IOException e){
System.out.println(e);
}
return out;
}
```